# Cassandra light weight transactions are failing for a single node cluster

Tags: cassandra, transactions, cql

I have a single node Cassandra cluster for simple development activities.
All usage works fine however if I attempt to perform a [LWT](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/lightweight-transactions-in-cassandra-2-0) then the query fails with a message indicating not enough hosts were available.

This makes sense if more hosts were configured however if all the hosts are available, which is 1, then it should succeed.

The error in CQLSH is NoHostAvailable.
Using the [C# driver from Datastax](http://www.nuget.org/packages/CassandraCSharpDriver/) it appears regardless of the consistency level, I tried several, the error is:

```
Not enough replicas available for query at consistency Quorum (2 required but only 1 alive)
```

The interesting thing is if I simply remove the "IF NOT EXISTS" from the CQL then the query succeeds.

Should Paxos even be used if there is a single node in the cluster?

Cassandra version:

```
 [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.11.1485 | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native protocol v4]
```

Keyspace:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE "XYZ" WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'Cassandra': '1', 'Solr': '1'}  AND durable_writes = true;
```

Nodetool ring:

```
    administrator@cassandra-dev01:~$ nodetool ring

Datacenter: Cassandra
==========
Address       Rack        Status State   Load            Owns                Token

10.10.98.200  rack1       Up     Normal  106.92 GB       ?                   -8300708032273586829

Datacenter: SearchGraphAnalytics
==========
Address       Rack        Status State   Load            Owns                Token

10.10.98.201  rack1       Up     Normal  13.79 MB        ?                   4478178638510484591
```

Comment: What does `nodetool ring` show?

Comment: I added the information. I am not sure if the search node counts as a cassandra node because it has a different purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like node in data center Solr is down or unreachable. When you say just Quorum and not local quorum it will actually go to the other node which is according to what you described.

Comment: There is a single node and then a search node from Datastax.

Comment: it looks like the data is not replicated to the second node / datacenter (192 GB one side and low MB on other one), can you run nodetool rebuild --SearchGraphAnalytics also The data centers that you specify as the replication factor (RF) for your keyspace must be predefined in either your cassandra-rackdc.properties or cassandra-topology.properties files (depending the Snitch you configured). Plus the names don't seem to match (Solr in create statement and SearchGraphAnalytics in ring command)

Comment: Anyway ... in your keyspace definition you have a Solr data center and when coordinator receives quorum it will try to contact it. If you are not using Solr data center update the keyspace with ALTER KEYSPACE "XYZ" WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'Cassandra': '1', 'Solr': '0', 'SearchGraphAnalytics': '0'}

Comment: This appears to be a misunderstand I had of how data flowed from Cassandra to the Datastax search node. I thought there was a single node cluster and search was different. I see that is not the case.